# Calculating Bayes' factor for 2 Gamma distributions

Tags: bayesian, inference, bayes-factors

I have 2 model $M_1$ and $M_2$ which both have a gamma distribution and the same priors

$H_0 : \quad x_i \sim M_1 \\ H_a: \quad x_i \sim M_2$

Both $M_1$ and $M_2$ have prior $\sim Ga(7,3000)$ but my posteriors are

$M_1 \sim Ga(191,116665.4) \\ M_2 \sim Ga(192, 116188.9)$

I get the values of my posterior via simulated data for both models. This means that I have simulated my data using $M_1$, then repeated the simulation but this time using $M_2$.

I now have an issue, as I am unsure whether I can calculate the Bayes factor for these 2 models now, because I have 2 lots of simulated data.

Would calculating the Bayes' factor for this data still be valid?

I know that my Bayes' factor $B$ should be

$B = \frac{Ga(191,116665.4)/Ga(7,3000)}{Ga(192, 116188.9)/Ga(7,3000)}$

But I don't know if this is a stupid calculation due to the earlier mentioned problem.

I'm really sorry if this isn't clear, I will try to explain better if it is not, but I've been thinking about this all day and I can't get my head around it.

Just for clarity, I basically want to test which model is better, $M_1$ or $M_2$ and I thought looking at the Bayes' factor would be useful in determining a superior model.

Any help/explanation would be so useful

Comment: The Bayes factor compares the fits of both models for the _same_ observed dataset. It is not relevant to compute _one realisation_  of the posterior by simulating a dataset under each model (and with which value of the parameter?).

Comment: So, what you're saying is that if I had some data X and I calculated the poesteriors for both models based on X I can then use that to calculate the Bayes factor? Because obviously to simulate my data, I have to use one of the models I want to test, so does this render this pointless?